# Spark SQL Collect_list(struct) saved as json

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Am having a hive table which needs to be generated as json file. In order to achieve it I have applied `collect_list(struct(fields..))`as A 
and saved it as json using `spark.write.json`.

But the json is having a additional index field "A" at beginning which I don't need. I just need array of json values. Am using pyspark

e.g.:

```
A:{[array of jsons]}
Expected: [array of json]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing as `Json` format, try to write in `CSV` format.

You can try casting `Array` type to `String` then write the data to HDFS directory.

**`Example:`**

**`Scala:`**

```
val df=Seq((1,2,3),(3,4,5),(1,3,1)).toDF("i","j","k")

val df1=df.groupBy("i").agg(collect_set("j").alias("j")).selectExpr("cast(j as string)j")

df1.repartition(1).write.option("quote", "\u0000").mode("overwrite").csv("<hdfs_path>")
```

**`Output data:`**

```
[2, 3]
[4]
```

> **(or)**

**`Pyspark:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([(1,2,3),(3,4,5),(1,3,1)],["i","j","k"])

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df1=df.groupBy("i").agg(collect_set("j").alias("j")).selectExpr("cast(j as string)j")

df1.repartition(1).write.option("quote", "").mode("overwrite").csv("<hdfs_path>")
```

**`Output data:`**

```
[2, 3]
[4]
```

Comment: I have tried this, it is showing the output as org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.unsafearraydata

Answer (score -1):

After generating `collect_list(struct)` into json . To remove the index `A`, I read it into a pandas dataframe and removed the index by saving it again as json 
Setting `orient='records'`.

Note: `collect_list` of struct only works with spark SQL. Hive doesn't support it